# return of getText() cannot be compared to a string

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am using a following code to compare 2 strings in one of protractor/jasmine test cases.

```
emailnotsentmessage.getText().then(function(text) {
          expect(text).toBe('has not received notification about recent changes to the meeting.');
        });
```

where emailnotsentmessage contains following text

```
[ 'has not received notification about recent changes to the meeting.' ]
```

for some reason , the string comparison fails . those two strings contains absolute same content. i checked it several times . am i missing something here ?. the **emailnotsentmessage**  is a content of a `<span>` .

error trace

```
1) Get to the existing meeting by navigating to the edit meeting page should display the same value which was entered du
ring create meeting when go into edit meeting
  Message:
    Expected [ 'has not received notification about recent changes to the meeting.' ] to equal 'has not received notific
ation about recent changes to the meeting.'.
  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
```

Comment: **[**] seem to be a part of **span** text. You are trying to compare without **[**]

Comment: thank you for your response . i tried with **[]** , but i get the same error .
`Failures:
1) Get to the existing meeting by navigating to the edit meeting page should display the same value which was entered du
ring create meeting when go into edit meeting
  Message:
    Expected [ 'has not received notification about recent changes to the meeting.' ] to be '[ 'has not received notific
ation about recent changes to the meeting.' ]'.
  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation`

Comment: Did you try the **array** thing as suggested by Felix?

Comment: yes. see the comment below his answer

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your `emailnotsentmessage` is **array** and not a string. What if you try `expect(text).toBe(['has not received notification about recent changes to the meeting.']);` or maybe `emailnotsentmessage[0]`

Comment: tried it . but it has the same result . 
`Failures:
1) Get to the existing meeting by navigating to the edit meeting page should display the same value which was entered du
ring create meeting when go into edit meeting
  Message:
    Expected [ 'has not received notification about recent changes to the meeting.' ] to be '[ 'has not received notific
ation about recent changes to the meeting.' ]'.
  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation`

Also i need to compare the string . not like **emailnotsentmessage[0]**

Answer (score 0):

found a fix and the reason behind this issue

i was earlier using `var emailnotsentmessage = element.all(by.css('css path'));` to get the element which caused the problem . It returns the string in an array format . instead i used the `element(by.css('css path'));` and it returns the expected string value .